# Как лучше сделать виджет погоды?

Tags: javascript, html, css

В голове есть несколько вариантов:

1) Есть контейнер, в который используя jquery всё грузится:

```
<script src="http://example.com/weather/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="example-weather-container"></div>
```

2) Используем iframe:

```
<iframe id="wbd-weather-widget" src="https://webdevkin.ru/examples/weather/widget/widget.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="280" height="122">
                Ваш браузер не поддерживает плавающие фреймы!
</iframe>
```

В чем отличие этих подходов? И какой из них лучше для виджета?

Comment: Зависит от Вашей архитектуры. Первый - построение "на месте", второй - подгрузка отдельной страницы со всеми вытекающими.

Comment: На данный момент ничего ещё нет. Данный вопрос как раз и задан, чтобы определиться с архитектурой. Мне нужны плюсы и минусы каждого пункта.

Comment: iframe - прошлый век, Вы никак не сможете вмешиваться в его содержимое, а с помощью js подгрузки, можно отлавливать события, изменять содержимое и редактировать стили

Comment: @aliokero, а что подробно не распишите? мне нужны плюсы и минусы.

Answer (score 5):

Главная проблема iframe в том, что не все современные смартфоны  правильно отображают его содержимое. Также при загрузке страницы, блоки могут быть размещены хаотично через наличие на странице iframe. В результате внешний вид сайта может быть испорчен. Посколько использование смартфонов и планшетов увеличивается, этого достаточно, чтобы отказатся от фрейма 
Стоит еще упомянуть проблему, которая иногда возникает в пользователей браузера IE 11, когда iframe не работает. И хотя большинство браузеров имеет неплохую поддержку фреймов, этих поблем у вас не будет при использовании джаваскрипта.
Хотя иногда блокировщики рекламы могут заблокировать содержимое, но это бывает очень-очень редко

Answer (score 3):

Начнем с того что фреймы - это прошлый век и на фреймы не делают ставку современные разработчики. Если адрес сайта, где хранится ваш виджет упадет - фрейм упадет и ничего не будет. Плюс как сказал автор выше - не все браузеры и тем более мобильные правильно его отображают. Тем более это лишний запрос на сторонний ресурс. 
В другом случае вы сразу подтягиваете код виджета `<script src='ваш URL'></script>` и в вашем div'е вы можете в крайнем случае стилизовать css ваш виджет, т.е. даже если виджет генериться полностью JS'кой, то доступ к его элементам в своем css-файле вы получите без проблем. Так же такой подход очень удобен для того, чтобы в дальнейшем интегрировать с вашим виджетом другие виджеты или скрипты. Плюс вы напрямую работаете в DOM'ом. Вариант со скриптом и дивом намного валидней и привлекательней выглядит. Даже вы сможете в своем js файле создать API вашего виджета и использовать на всей странице.  
 IFrame делает изоляцию и обратиться к странице в нем вы не сможете. Тем более вам в комментариях уже сказали - iframe грузит всю страницу, соответственно лишний запрос, лишнее время загрузки.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется исходя из того, что в iframe не возможно вмешаться уже наводит на мысль что это не удобно и не практично. Для корректировки придется постоянно лезть на хост где лежит виджет.

Но с другой стороны этот минус может стать, плюсом если вам нужно защитить свой код от изменений.

Answer (score 2):

Ответьте себе, для начала, на такие вопросы:
**-Чего именно вы хотите добиться от виджета погоды?**

**-Какой в нём должен быть контент?**

**-Откуда вы будете тянуть данные?**

Врят ли вы будете хранить данные у себя на сервере. И если я прав - то ваш выбор - `js`. Вам ведь в любом случае нужно писать функционал получения, парса и расстановки данных. Если  то, что вы будете подгружать в `iframe` - ваша разработка, то, как я уже сказал, пишите всё у себя. Из плюсов - так будет быстрее отрабатывать, проще реагировать на действия над виджетом, менять там цвета и применять прочие плюшки, которые сложно сделать средствами `css` и вёрстки.

Явных плюсов в использовании `iframe` я не вижу, это скажем "для ленивых", или когда нет возможности писать `js` или серверный код для получения данных. Т.е. оперируете исключительно вёрсткой. В таком случае это даже не лучше, а просто единственный возможный вариант.